# Does "aristocratic" have a derogatory meaning in current usage?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

If I wish to describe someone by "aristocratic" and mean simply that the person is elegant and confident, will the person being described get offended by this word? In general, does this word "aristocratic" have any derogatory meaning in current usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean to say that the person is elegant and confident, I would suggest saying that:

> Debbie is elegant and confident.

If you want to add *aristocratic* for the comparison purposes, I think the word has too many subtle nuances to be clear and unambiguous. I think Meaning #3 at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aristocratic) explains it well:

> **a·ris·to·crat·ic** (*adjective*) characteristic of an aristocrat; having the manners, values, or qualities associated with the aristocracy: *aristocratic bearing; aristocratic snobbishness*.

Those two examples seem interesting to me: *aristoctratic bearing* would be a compliment; *aristocratic snobbishness* would be an insult. Calling a person simply "aristocratic" would be a loaded statement, and many might wonder if some kind of subtle insult was intended.

This option might work well, though:

> Debbie has the elegance and confidence of an aristocrat.

Because elegance and confidence are generally regarded as positive traits, people would be less likely to wonder if the word was meant to have a negative connotation.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on context, *aristocratic* could be used either to praise or to express one's disdain for someone.

I guess that when context is absent, there's no negative connotation attached to the word in the way it is attached to the word *[toff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toff)*, say, or to the adjective *foppish*.